# Notify When TFS User Story Changes

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

At my daily work, I have to follow multiple Team foundation tasks or user stories. Sometimes, I create a task to other teams and they change status of this task to verified level unexpectedly. But after I control this task and realized that its not working correctly.

**NOTE**: I tried to use custom alerts but could not find anything about related work items.

**NOTE2** : TFS 2015.

Is there any way to be notify when someone changes your task's status to verified before telling me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a work item alert (if email is enabled on the server) and specify a query where you can set `"Created by" == @me` as query to get email.

Go to notifications or alerts (depending on your TFS version) and create a new work item based alert. Then create a work item query that lists the work items you want to be notified about.

In TFS 2017 and VSTS you can also "follow" a work item:
[image]

Comment: Using tfs 2015 there is no follow button

Comment: @nolines TFS 2015 doesn't have the follow button, you could update to TFS 2017. Or create a workitem alert to notice you when those workitems changes.